# about Ethereum governance

Tags: governance

could anyone tell me about Ethereum's decision making. I am new about that.

for example

- how the roadmap decided or who decide it
- how make decision of softfork or hardfork
- how appropriate code is committed and merged and who does it
- is there any admin of nodes(like masternode)
- how can we join as a core member who can be on Core Devs Meeting
- is there any voting to ask to node for developing

I am currently researching about governance in crypto industry
thanks,

Comment: I mainly want to know how Ethereum's off-chain governance work.